# How to set preference for auto-downloading excel in firefox using robot framework

Tags: firefox, robotframework

I am new to robot framework. I was trying to override save dialog box so that Excel files get auto-downloaded without asking in FireFox, however, have been unable to do so.

Can anyone help me and tell what should I pass for auto-downloading Excel 97-2003 worksheet in below line of code in place of `application/csv`

This is written in python and then am using it in test case as below:

```
  **Python code**:
  def create_profile(path):
  from selenium import webdriver
  fp =webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
  fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
  fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
  fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir",path)
  fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",'application/csv')
  fp.update_preferences()
  return fp.path

  **Test case:**
  ${random_string}    generate random string  3       
  ${path} Catenate    SEPARATOR=\\    ${TEMPDIR}  ${random_string}
  ${profile_path}= create_profile  ${path}
  open browser    ${app_url}  ff  ff_profile_dir=${profile_path}
```

Note:I tried giving options as `application/excel`, `application/x-excel`, `application/msexcel` but still dialog box is displayed during automation.

Comment: Can you provide us with a more complete example of your robot script and Python code? In general it's best to provide a minimal non-working example  so that others may replicate and help.

Comment: I was using the code as mentioned in one of the stack overflow question's answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33198814/how-to-set-preferences-for-firefox-in-robot-framework.Have added the code in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following:

```
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/xls;text/csv");
```

Comment: I am still getting the Save dialog box.

Comment: Try adding below in the preference

application/x-msexcel,application/excel,application/x-excel,application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: Ok will try this as well,is there any documentation available for this which I can go through.I need same for downloading .tsv files as well.Thanks in advance